# PostgreSQL: How to insert, select, and update values with underscores

Tags: postgresql, escaping

I have a table that has a column, `file_name`. I added file names that contain underscores using `insert`.  Upon `select` I see spaces where the underscores should be. Apparently the underscore is used for formatting and needs to be escaped.

1. What is the proper way to `insert` values with underscores?
2. How can I `update` the values with spaces by replacing all spaces with underscores?
3. What is the proper way to `select` a row using `where` when the value has an underscore, such as `where file_name = "some_file.txt"`

In other words, how and when does the underscore need to be escaped?

Comment: If you view your data in pgAdmin, some versions on some platforms use a default row height in which the underscores are clipped. Just drag the bottom of the row to a larger height to see all characters completely.

Comment: wow, you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to escape underscores in string literals in Postgres. [See this example.](http://rextester.com/GGB95228) Your case may be caused by a strange behavior of client application. Test your queries in psql.